# Is there a requirement to fast if Ebola is reported in the city?

Tags: fast-days, choleh-sick, current-events, masechet-taanis

I remember learning in mesechet Taanis that if there is a plague in the city with a certain number of people and there are people dying daily that the city should declare a fast. Is there any contemporary application of this? For example if there is, God forbid, a community where there are cases of Ebola reported and people are dying is there an obligation for that community to declare a fast?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47475/759 Don't ever ever ever fast if it compromises your ability to fight off a local infectious disease.

Comment: @DoubleAA that determination should be made by competent (and God fearing) medical expert in conjunction with a Rabbi I assume. I am asking the question theoretically in any case

Comment: Ebola is not spread by casual contact, and even then only by people with symptoms ([CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/vhf/ebola/outbreaks/2014-west-africa/qa.html)). So merely being in the same city as a few Ebola victims does not present a serious danger, assuming appropriate precautions are being taken ("the risk of an outbreak in the U.S. is very low").

Comment: http://5tjt.com/ebola-a-halachic-perspective/