# What is the difference between a sickness and a plague?

Tags: fast-days, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, choleh-sick

Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim, Siman 576) discusses fasting and praying for *Dever* (a plague), and also for a sickness (*choli*). What is the difference between sickness and plague?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/111979/torah-response-to-epidemics

Comment: see nedarim 41b